# How many rejections in the observations are needed to reject the null hypothesis in a two-tailed test?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution

I am new to statistics. I have some basic questions to ask. Suppose we flip a coin for 500 times, we repeat the coin flipping trail for 1000 times and  the null hypothesis is:

*The probability of getting 250 or fewer heads in 500 coin flips is 0.5*

If we consider 0.01 for the significance level in the *two-tailed test*, to calculate the lower critical value we have: `qbinom(0.005,500,0.5,TRUE) = 221` and also for the upper critical value `qbinom(0.005,500,0.5,FALSE) = 279` where `0.005 = significance level / 2`.
Suppose after all of those 1000 repetitions are done, we get 213 , 210 , 220 , 218, 217 , 219 number of heads (which all are less than lower critical value) and also we observe 280, 285, 281 , 282, 285, 283, 287 (which all are greater than upper critical value). Accordingly, in the 6 (out of 1000) repetitions of those 500-coin-flipping the number of heads are in the lower rejection region and in the 7 (out of 1000) repetitions the number of heads are in the upper rejection region. Since the significance level is 0.01 then its half is 0.005 then `1000(number of repetition) x 0.005 = 5` so as we have 6 observations in the lower rejection region and 6 > 5 and also 7 observations in upper critical region and 7 > 5 then we reject the null hypothesis.

Now my question is:
Am I calculating the criteria of rejecting the null hypothesis correctly? or should I just calculate `1000(number of repetition) x significance_level(and not its half) = 10`? and then as 6 and 7 are less than 10 then the null hypothesis is accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, it is edited now.

Comment: A hypothesis is a statement about a population (typically about a population parameter), not about sample outcomes.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica So shall I use the mean of those outcomes and if the mean is inside acceptance region then accept null hypothesis?

Comment: I am suggesting that you start by writing a hypothesis that's actually a hypothesis. At that point it might hopefully be somewhat clearer what you need.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Can you please give a hint?

Comment: I would have guessed that you're interested in the hypothesis of a fair coin (i.e. that $P(\text{Head}) = \frac12$) were it not for the fact that your statement isn't actually consistent with that (since your probability statement - the thing you called a null hypothesis - suggests you think P(head) is slightly less than 1/2). It's exactly that inconsistency between what one might expect and what you write that would be resolved by an explicit hypothesis about the population proportion of heads.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica So what I conclude is to change null hypothesis to _the coin is fair_ as you mentioned, then calculate the mean of heads from that 1000 repetition, if the mean is inside the acceptance region we accept the null hypothesis. I hope I have understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes, but rather if the number (or proportion, it doesn't matter which statistic you use) of heads is in the rejection region you reject the null, otherwise you fail to reject it.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thanks a lot. It was a great help.